# MLKit Barcode Scanner does not finish its calculations

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I am testing MLKit Barcode scanner functionality, but its processing does not end. I had to finish its calculation after 10000ms so that the further processing goes in normal manner.

I have tried previous versions of MLKit barcode. My current packages are:

```
   compileSdk 34
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-java:16.1.0'
```

The very code is as following (Java)

```
public class MyBarcodeScannerMLKit {
    @NonNull
    private final BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner;


    public MyBarcodeScannerMLKit() {
        barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(getCustomBarcodeScannerOptions());
    }

    @NonNull
    private BarcodeScannerOptions getCustomBarcodeScannerOptions() {
        return new BarcodeScannerOptions
                .Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_PDF417)
                .enableAllPotentialBarcodes()
                .build();
    }
    @Nullable
    public String findBarcode(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
        List<String> barcodesMLKit = Tasks.await(barcodeScanner.process(inputImage),
                10000,
                java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .stream()
                .map(Barcode::getDisplayValue)
                .filter(value -> !Objects.equals(value, ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (barcodesMLKit.isEmpty()) return null;
        return barcodesMLKit.get(0);
    }
}
```

Every single barcode I have passed (approx 200 x 100px image) results in timeout error.

Comment: Did you see any error logs from ML Kit libraries?

Comment: No sign of any error in MLKit, logs - only info about Timeout, but these are provided by myself.

Comment: Did you code this instruction: barcodeScanner= new BarcodeScannerMLKit();

Comment: @SudoKoach yes, I have indeed. I haven't the exact code as the root of the problem is the method call displayed above, none of the barcodes passed to scan finish its processing in other way than throwing `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Task`. I have chcecked that proper images are going on scanner input (but I suppose scanner should work even if there is no barcode on image).

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks, the Tasks.await is a static method that returns the Task's result.  That means the Tasks.await must be called from outside the BarcodeScannerMLKit class.

Comment: @SudoKoach I have changed code for clarity - MyBarcodeScannerMLKit class is mine to manage, I do use Task.await outside the Google's MLKit class. Is it enough? I think so.

Comment: @user12992700 See my answer below.

Comment: It may be useful I do use findBarcode in separate thread. Would you like to explain to me why Tasks.await should be used outside this class?

Comment: In § Threading of page https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks, it’s written: “Listeners attached to a thread are run on the application main (UI) thread by default.” The task “barcodeScanner.process(inputImage).” is a thread running on the app main thread and Tasks.await is the “parent” thread running also on the app main thread. So there is a conflict of threads. In the § it’s also written “When attaching a listener, you can also specify an Executor that is used to schedule listeners.” Never tried to apply that suggestion. That could be a good challenge.

Comment: @user12992700 Check out this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457397/can-i-run-five-text-recognizer-synchronously. It's an interesting use case of a specific Executor and the function await.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short snippet tested that doesn't make use of the Tasks.await() method.

```
public class BarcodeReader {

    BarcodeScanner barcodereader;

    public BarcodeReader() {
        barcodereader = BarcodeScanning.getClient();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    void readBarcode(Bitmap bmp) {
        
        InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bmp, 0);
        Task<List<Barcode>> result = barcodereader.process(image);

/* barcodetext is a TextView in MainActivity layout. 

   Waiting for the Task result to be complete.
   The flag "isComplete()" is triggered whatever
                        the result: success or failure. 
*/
        while (!result.isComplete()) {
            barcodetext.setText("");
        }
        barcodetext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (result.isSuccessful() && !result.getResult().isEmpty()) {
            Barcode barcode = result.getResult().get(0);
            barcodetext.setText(barcode.getRawValue());
        } else {
            barcodetext.setText(">>>>> Reading error!");
        }
        barcodereader.close();
    }
}

public class MainActivity {
    .....
    
/* Calling instructions in MainActivity. */
    BarcodeReader barcodereader = new BarcodeReader();
    Bitmap bmp=previewView.getBitmap();
    barcodereader.readBarcode(bmp);
    
    ......
}
```

Comment: I cannot affort not to implement it like that, I cannot wait infinite time for result, only 10s, then I should behave as if there were no barcode - this is exactly why I have used Tasks.await

Comment: It doesn't take infinite time to read the barcode!!!! It's instant once the barcode reader is triggered. A timeout is essentially required for debugging. May be your app just requires an ImageAnalysis.Analyzer. Check out: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android.