# Can I run five text recognizer synchronously?

Tags: google-mlkit

I want to run 5 text recognizers simultaneously and try to achieve it through the following code.

```
class LocalOCRTestActivity : BaseActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "LocalOCRTestActivity"
    }

    override fun layoutId(): Int = R.layout.activity_local_ocr_test

    private val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 10, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS, LinkedBlockingQueue(20))

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val imgPath = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_QUESTION_LOCAL_PIC) ?: ""
        ivOcr.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(File(imgPath)))

        val image = InputImage.fromFilePath(this, Uri.fromFile(File(imgPath)))

        lifecycleScope.safeLaunch(Dispatchers.IO, exceptionHandler = { exception ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "exception: ${exception.message}")
        }) {
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call recognizer")

            val LatinRecognizer = async { performTextRecognition(image) }
            val ChineseRecognizer = async { performChineseTextRecognition(image) }
            val DevanagariRecongizer = async { performDevanagariTextRecognition(image) }
            val JapaneseRecognizer = async { performJapaneseTextRecognition(image) }
            val KoreanRecognizer = async { performKoreanTextRecognition(image) }

            val KoreanText = KoreanRecognizer.await()
            val JapaneseText = JapaneseRecognizer.await()
            val DevanagariText = DevanagariRecongizer.await()
            val ChineseText = ChineseRecognizer.await()
            val LatinText = LatinRecognizer.await()

            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "recognizer done")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performTextRecognition(image: InputImage): Text {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build())
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call performTextRecognition 11111")
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    LogDelegate.d(TAG, "latin recognize success 11111")
                    continuation.resume(text)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performChineseTextRecognition(image: InputImage): Text {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(ChineseTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build())
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call performChineseTextRecognition 22222")
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    LogDelegate.d(TAG, "chinese recognize success 22222")
                    continuation.resume(text)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performDevanagariTextRecognition(image: InputImage): Text {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(DevanagariTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build())
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call performDevanagariTextRecognition 33333")
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    LogDelegate.d(
                        TAG,
                        "Devanagari recognize success 33333"
                    )
                    continuation.resume(text)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performJapaneseTextRecognition(image: InputImage): Text {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(JapaneseTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build())
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call performJapaneseTextRecognition 44444")
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    LogDelegate.d(TAG, "Japanese recognize success 44444")
                    continuation.resume(text)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performKoreanTextRecognition(image: InputImage): Text {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(KoreanTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build())
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            LogDelegate.d(TAG, "call performKoreanTextRecognition 55555")
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    LogDelegate.d(TAG, "Korean recognize success 55555")
                    continuation.resume(text)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect 5 detectors to run in parallel.However, from the results, it looks more like a serial execution：

```
2023-11-10 10:21:02.661 29695-32549 LocalOCRTestActivity    call recognizer

2023-11-10 10:21:02.663 29695-30652 LocalOCRTestActivity    call performChineseTextRecognition 22222

2023-11-10 10:21:02.665 29695-32550 LocalOCRTestActivity    call performDevanagariTextRecognition 33333

2023-11-10 10:21:02.667 29695-32549 LocalOCRTestActivity    call performKoreanTextRecognition 55555 

2023-11-10 10:21:02.668 29695-30612 LocalOCRTestActivity    call performTextRecognition 11111 

2023-11-10 10:21:02.670 29695-30650 LocalOCRTestActivity    call performJapaneseTextRecognition 44444 

2023-11-10 **10:21:03.141** 29695-29695 LocalOCRTestActivity    chinese recognize success 22222

2023-11-10 **10:21:03.483** 29695-29695 LocalOCRTestActivity    Devanagari recognize success 33333 

2023-11-10 **10:21:04.015** 29695-29695 LocalOCRTestActivity    Korean recognize success 55555

2023-11-10 **10:21:04.269** 29695-29695 LocalOCRTestActivity    latin recognize success 11111 

2023-11-10 **10:21:04.678** 29695-29695 LocalOCRTestActivity    Japanese recognize success 44444

2023-11-10 10:21:04.681 29695-32549 LocalOCRTestActivity    recognizer done
```

I want to confirm if there is any problem with the above code?
Does the text recognizer support parallel invocation?

Comment: Your question is a question of principle. The single LogDelegate thread attached to the main thread can only handle one addOnSuccessListener at a time.

Comment: @SudoKoach Thank you for your answer. Because I don’t know the language of the original text, I want to call 5 TextRecognition in parallel to shorten the time. However, from the running results of the above code, it seems that it is still serial. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no solution available for this 'single client/server' use case.

There is only one thread executor (server) and the 5 text recognizers are launched sequentially (serially).

```
private val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 10, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS, LinkedBlockingQueue(20))

val LatinRecognizer = async { performTextRecognition(image) }
val ChineseRecognizer = async { performChineseTextRecognition(image) }
val DevanagariRecongizer = async { performDevanagariTextRecognition(image) }
val JapaneseRecognizer = async { performJapaneseTextRecognition(image) }
val KoreanRecognizer = async { performKoreanTextRecognition(image) }
```

Likewise, the 5 results can only be processed in sequence by the single user (client).

```
val KoreanText = KoreanRecognizer.await()
val JapaneseText = JapaneseRecognizer.await()
val DevanagariText = DevanagariRecongizer.await()
val ChineseText = ChineseRecognizer.await()
val LatinText = LatinRecognizer.await()
```

Keep in mind that parallel processing is just an illusion when there's a bottleneck, such that data can only be processed in series.

Can one read two pages from a book at once? Even the fastest scanner performs it in series!